# How to change Vertical and Horizontal ScrollBar in a single style

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

I'm developing a new design for ScrollBar. I could not make horizontal and vertical scroll work together properly in the design. I do not apply both at the same time.

The template below works fine for portrait but not for landscape.

```
                    <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs"
                       TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                               Width="Auto"
                                               Height="Auto"
                                               Fill="Transparent" />
                                    <Border x:Name="Rectangle1"
                                            CornerRadius="5"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Width="Auto"
                                            Height="Auto"
                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="LightGray" />
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                            Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                                <Grid x:Name="GridRoot"
                                      Width="10">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                           IsDirectionReversed="true"
                                           Focusable="false">
                                        <Track.Thumb>
                                            <Thumb x:Name="Thumb"
                                                   Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                                   Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                                        </Track.Thumb>
                                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp"
                                                          Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"
                                                          Opacity="0"
                                                          Focusable="false" />
                                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                            <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown"
                                                          Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                                                          Opacity="0"
                                                          Focusable="false" />
                                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    </Track>
                                </Grid>

                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                             Property="IsMouseOver"
                                             Value="true">
                                        <Setter Value="DarkGray"
                                                TargetName="Thumb"
                                                Property="Background" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                             Property="IsDragging"
                                             Value="true">
                                        <Setter Value="DimGray"
                                                TargetName="Thumb"
                                                Property="Background" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
```

This code below works fine for landscape but does not work for portrait.

```
       <Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs"
          TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                   <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                       <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  Width="Auto"
                                  Height="Auto"
                                  Fill="Transparent" />
                       <Border x:Name="Rectangle1"
                               CornerRadius="5"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                               Width="Auto"
                               Height="Auto"
                               Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                   </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>

   <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}"
          TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
       <Setter Property="Foreground"
               Value="LightGray" />
       <Setter Property="Background"
               Value="Transparent" />
       <Setter Property="Width"
               Value="690" />
       <Setter Property="Height"
               Value="10" />
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                   <Grid x:Name="GridRoot"
                         Width="690"
                         Height="10">
                       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
                       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                       <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              IsDirectionReversed="False"
                              Focusable="True">
                           <Track.Thumb>
                               <Thumb x:Name="Thumb"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                      Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                           </Track.Thumb>
                           <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                               <RepeatButton x:Name="PageRight"
                                             Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand"
                                             Opacity="0"
                                             Focusable="false" />
                           </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                           <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                               <RepeatButton x:Name="PageLeft"
                                             Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand"
                                             Opacity="0"
                                             Focusable="false" />
                           </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                       </Track>
                   </Grid>

                   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                       <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                Property="IsMouseOver"
                                Value="true">
                           <Setter Value="DarkGray"
                                   TargetName="Thumb"
                                   Property="Background" />
                       </Trigger>
                       <Trigger SourceName="Thumb"
                                Property="IsDragging"
                                Value="true">
                           <Setter Value="DimGray"
                                   TargetName="Thumb"
                                   Property="Background" />
                       </Trigger>
                   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
```

How can I combine the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with orientation trigger. Set regular style ControlTemplate and then in trigger overwrite your ControlTemplate to horizontal style.
Here's example code (not my, but tested works)

```
<!--ScrollBarr Style-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressGradient" EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0.9,0.9">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF254639"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF3C784D" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Border" Color="White"/>
<Style x:Key="ProgressBarStyleRounded" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ProgressGradient}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ProgressBar.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.25"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.25"/>
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0.25"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransformOrigin)">
                                        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-0.5,0.5"/>
                                        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
                                        <EasingPointKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="1.5,0.5"/>
                                    </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border CornerRadius="6" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" />
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Indicator" ClipToBounds="true" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Animation" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="TemplateRoot">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--ScrollBarr Style-->
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border x:Name="rectangle"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                            Background="#0c6991"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-14 0 0 0" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent">

                    <Border Padding="0 4">
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                           IsDirectionReversed="true"
                           IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                           Width="6"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Opacity="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" />
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Opacity="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" />
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 -14 0 0" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                Height="6"
                                   >
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Opacity="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand}"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Opacity="0" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageRightCommand}"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" />
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="0"/>

                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" 
                               Opacity="0.2"
                               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" 
                               Cursor="Arrow" 
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" 
                               Minimum="0" 
                               Grid.Row="0" 
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                               Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"/>

                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Opacity="0.2"
                               AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Cursor="Arrow" 
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               Minimum="0" 
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1" 
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                               Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"/>

                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.2" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.2" Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```